# Elasticsearch: Cannot update parameter [analyzer] from [default] to [autocomplete]

Tags: elasticsearch

So folks, I started my studies with elasticsearch and started trying to build an autocomplete with edge - ngram tokenizer on my machine and found a problem when trying to follow the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en%20/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) for such a configuration.

I followed the following steps:

1. I created my index with a standard configuration as the documentation requested:

   ```
    {
       "settings": {
          "analysis": {
             "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                   "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
                     "filter": [
                       "lowercase"
                     ]
                 },
                 "autocomplete_search": {
                    "tokenizer": "lowercase"
                 }
              },
              "tokenizer": {
                 "autocomplete": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 10,
                    "token_chars": [
                       "letter"
                    ]
                 }
              }
           }
        }
    }
   ```
2. I added an item to the index via bulk:

   ```
    {"index":{"_index":"products","_type":"products"}}{"sku":"73792589","name":"Bruno's test","img":"73792589_5911_20201229172349.jpg,73792589_5911_20201229172349.jpg,73792589_5911_20201229172349.jpg,73792589_5911_20201229172349.jpg,73792589_5911_20201229172349.jpg,73792589_5911_20201229172349.jpg,73792589_5911_20201229172349.jpg,73792589_5911_20201229172349.jpg","avaliacao":0,"preco_de":159,"preco_por":143.1}
   ```
3. I tried to update the field mapping to reference my custom analyzer

Problem: When trying to proceed with step 3, the following error is returned to me:

```
[REQUEST] _mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "autocomplete",
      "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }  
      }
    },
    "sku": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "autocomplete",
      "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }  
      }
    }
  }
}

[RESPONSE]
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Mapper for [name] conflicts with existing mapper:\n\tCannot update parameter [analyzer] from [default] to [autocomplete]"
        }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Mapper for [name] conflicts with existing mapper:\n\tCannot update parameter [analyzer] from [default] to [autocomplete]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding the `settings` for the `products` index, you have indexed the data without any explicit mapping defined. So, the [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html) is generated.

The mapping of your index is

```
{
  "products": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "avaliacao": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "img": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "preco_de": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "preco_por": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "sku": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Now you are trying to update the mapping of the index (in the 3rd step). You want to add the `analyzer` parameter along with the fields, but this cannot be done.* This is because when updating the index mapping you can -

1. Add new properties to an existing object field
2. Add multi-fields to an existing field
3. Change the mapping of an existing field
4. Rename a field

To know more about the [update mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#put-mapping-api-example), refer to this documentation

---

*(You need to first delete the `products` index)* Follow the below steps to index the bulk data (with proper index mapping)

**1. First Step: Index Mapping**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "tokenizer": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "sku": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Second Step: Index Bulk data**

```
POST/ _bulk

{"index":{"_index":"products","_type":"products"}}
{"sku":"73792589","name":"Bruno's test","img":"73792589_5911_20201229172349.jpg,73792589_5911_20201229172349.jpg,73792589_5911_20201229172349.jpg,73792589_5911_20201229172349.jpg,73792589_5911_20201229172349.jpg,73792589_5911_20201229172349.jpg,73792589_5911_20201229172349.jpg,73792589_5911_20201229172349.jpg","avaliacao":0,"preco_de":159,"preco_por":143.1}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! But when I try to do that I receive the same error (Only in _bulk).  `{    "took": 1,     "errors": true,     "items": [         {             "index": {                  "_index": "products",   "_type": "products",                 "_id": "2GdtsngBzb9JEGcmhSyR",                 "status": 400,                  "error": {                     "type": "illegal_argument_exception",                     "reason": "Mapper for [name] conflicts with existing mapper:\n\tCannot update parameter [analyzer] from 
 autocomplete] to [default]"                 }             }         },`

Comment: @BrunoHenriqueGaignouxGomes You need to first delete the `products` index, and then create a new index with new index mapping

Comment: @BrunoHenriqueGaignouxGomes any update here ?

Comment: I've do that man. But got the same error... I made an worker to do that for me and via postman I create the test items one by one. Thanks for helping!